On mobile Safari, how can a form's tab order be kept intact when elements overlay parts of the form?
I built an HTML form including some text inputs which, when focused on, open a container presenting suggestions. This works fine in Firefox, but I discovered that on mobile Safari (iOS 15.7.1), when the container is shown, since it overlays the input fields after it, Safari's "next field" arrow-down button no longer works (it is displayed but doesn't move the focus).
The visibility of that container is directly associated with the input element's focus.
It appears as if, with parts of the form in the background through overlaying elements, it's tab order is reinterpreted, making the "unvisible" fields inaccessible.
Is there a way to prevent this and keep the general appearance intact?
HTML:
<form>
    <table>
    <tr>
        <th align="left"><label for="a">A</label></th>
        <td width="100%">
            <div class="fetch_container">
                <div class="fetch"></div>
            </div>
            <input type="text" id="a" class="fetch_input" name="a" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th align="left"><label for="b">B</label></th>
        <td width="100%">
            <div class="fetch_container">
                <div class="fetch"></div>
            </div>
            <input type="text" id="b" class="fetch_input" name="b" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th align="left"><label for="c">C</label></th>
        <td width="100%"><input type="text" id="c" name="c" /></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

CSS:
.fetch_container {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 2rem;
}

.fetch {
    position: absolute;
    display: table-row;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 0.2rem;
    border: 1px solid #55f;
    width: 100%;
}

.fetch:empty {
    display: none;
}

I experimented with HTML's tabindex property, but this didn't help.
Also, I tried adjusting the CSS in various ways and positioning the element with JS, but from what I can tell, as long as the .fetch_container ends up being displayed above any of the form's inputs (even when only partially), those end up not being accessible through Safari's "next input" button.
